# Device=ansiibm.sys in DOSBox

Tags: dosbox

Some of my old DOS programs require the following command line in config.sys or config.nt:

device=ansiibm.sys

How do I accomplish this in DOSBox?  I've tried putting this line in the config options file--didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no direct config.sys emulation in DosBox.  One of the developers was asked about it on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/dosbox/feature-requests/56/).  He said that "You can however boot a version of dos inside dosbox (using the boot command) in that version you can put what you like."

I looked into the [Boot Command](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/BOOT), and it uses DOS drive images, if you have any.  This replaces the DosBox directories, so it may not be what you're looking for.

However, I found some interesting information [here](http://home.earthlink.net/~infernosadventures/configuringdosemulation.htm), regarding MSDOS emulation in Windows XP.  I didn't know this before, but you can set up custom config.sys and autoexec.bat files within a shortcut to a command prompt.  It even allows you to change the hardware timer emulation, so that old DOS programs (games) don't operate way too quickly :)

I hope some of this helps!

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that doesn't help here.  There is an autoexec section in the DOSBox config file, so I wonder if there is a way to convert a config.nt command to an autoexec.nt command.

Comment: @Transpower Sorry it didn't help.  If you find a solution, you're encouraged to post it as an answer to your own question :)  Of course, hopefully someone will post a good answer any minute now!

Comment: I found ansi.com and nansi.com and nnansi.com (all available for free download) and tried each of them in the autoexec section of the DOSBox config file, but they didn't work: the columns in one of my programs are still misaligned. Now that Microsoft has released the source code for MSDOS 1 and 2 I wonder if the DOSBox developers can improve their product? There really needs to be a config.sys or config.nt file!